# position:relative moving image to foreground

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a Comodo trust logo on my site. It is an image that when you mouse over it, it pops up an iframe with some security info about the site. The code to do this comes from a third party.

The problem comes when the logo is near a relatively positioned image. The image shows up on top of the iframe. If I remove `position:relative;` from my footer image, the iframe shows up on top of the image. I can't just remove relative positioning though, because it throws off the look of the rest of the page.

I've distilled the issue into a jsFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SCSFP/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trust logo is injecting a `div` into the page with a `z-index` set to 0, so essentially it's being placed behind everything else (including your image).

Changing the `z-index` to any other positive integer will change the `iframe`'s stacking order and place it on top of the image (as long as its higher than your image's `z-index`, which is 1 unless explicitly set).

Adding this to your stylesheet should do the trick (assuming that logo always generates a `div` with the same ID):

```
#tl_popupSC5{
    z-index:1 !important;        
}
```

Note that the `div` containing the frame has its `z-index` set via an inline style, so you will need to make sure that's overridden properly.

Comment: Thank you, I had never heard of `!important` before. That's very handy.

Comment: Use it judiciously! It's a great way to force rules to have the highest specificity possible, but it also makes rules extremely difficult to override. Only use it in very specific cases!

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index` css property.

```
#baselineImage
{
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:-6;
    z-index:-1;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCSFP/1/